# the property 'uid' cant be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be null

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, dart-null-safety, null-safety

i am trying to return value in users where i am getting this error if i am trying to fix this error by adding null sign it does not return any value becuase all this value is going to be null and i want to return this value and save it so i can use it what can be the solution Please guide

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

Future<void> addUser(context) {
  //before we add user we need to check this user already signedin earlier using same number or not
  //if signedIn before no need to add , because it may have added already. so just need to skip adduser




  return users
      .add({
    'uid': user.uid,
    'mobile':  user.phoneNumber,
    'email': user.email
  })
      .then((value){
        //after add data to firebase then will go to next screen
    //if you pushreplacementName or push replacement, then u cant go back to previous screen
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, LocationScreen.id);

  })
      .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add user: $error"));
}
```

Comment: I doubt there is someone who will understand what you want to achieve. Edit your question, so people can understand you.

Comment: You "user" variable is nullable.

It means that you have to check if "user" is null before accessing its properties (uid, phoneNumber...)

Comment: @Octet yes , it is nullable, if i removed it will throw nullable exception. Is there another way to resolve it becuase i am not getting my data back to firestore. It's showing null values in firestore. and i dont know why. i want to return value of users saved in it on runtime

Comment: It just means that the user is not logged in when you call addUser().

That's why you have to check inside addUser() is user is null or not

Comment: @Octet yes you right it's not logged in but what i was trying to do is pass these values in those variables by retuning it 

but i resolved it  by simply declaring it first seprately and then used it later let me show you how `User? user` **simply delcaring it seprately** 
`user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;`  **and used it seprately**

Answer (score 0):

that is because **uid** is nullable.
try this

```
 return users
      .add({
    'uid': user.uid ?? "default username"
    'mobile':  user.phoneNumber,
    'email': user.email
  })
```

**default username** will be saved in firestore if **uid** is null.

Comment: yes you are right it's returning "default username" but i want to return the user values which are written on runtime and want to return to the firestore.

Comment: it seems like you need to make sure you have stored the user input value in the user.uid variable before storing in firestore.  can you provide me the code where you ask for the user input

Comment: yes you are right but it was not storing it and was giving error i dont know why 
but i resolved it by simply declaring is it first seprately and then used it later 

let me show you how 

`User? user`   **simply delcaring it seprately**
`user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;`   **and used it seprately**